# Rails not Uploading Image to Cloudinary. Frontend is JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, file-upload, cloudinary

One of the things I want to do in my Rails and JavaScript project is to upload images. I'm trying Cloudinary, but unfortunately, my efforts haven't been successful.

First, I installed the gem and got the cloudinary.yml file as required. Then, I updated the environments/development.rb file.

```
  # Store uploaded files on the local file system (see config/storage.yml for options).
  config.active_storage.service = :cloudinary
```

I also updated the config/storage.yml file with my `api_key` and `api_secret`.

```
test:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>

local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>

cloudinary:
  service: Cloudinary
```

I added :img to the DB and also did `rails active_storage:install` to add the additional active storage tables to the migration.

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2022_01_12_024135) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "active_storage_attachments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name", null: false
    t.string "record_type", null: false
    t.bigint "record_id", null: false
    t.bigint "blob_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.index ["blob_id"], name: "index_active_storage_attachments_on_blob_id"
    t.index ["record_type", "record_id", "name", "blob_id"], name: "index_active_storage_attachments_uniqueness", unique: true
  end

  create_table "active_storage_blobs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "key", null: false
    t.string "filename", null: false
    t.string "content_type"
    t.text "metadata"
    t.bigint "byte_size", null: false
    t.string "checksum", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.index ["key"], name: "index_active_storage_blobs_on_key", unique: true
  end

  create_table "albums", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "artist"
    t.string "genre"
    t.string "condition"
    t.string "description"
    t.integer "price"
    t.integer "category_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.string "img"
  end

  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  add_foreign_key "active_storage_attachments", "active_storage_blobs", column: "blob_id"
end
```

I've also added the following in the Controller:

```
def img
        file_url = Cloudinary::Uploader.upload(params[:file], options = {})
end 

    private

    def album_params
        params.require(:album).permit(:name, :artist, :genre, :condition, :description, :price, :img, :category_id)
    end
```

`:img` was also added in the album serializer, and I added `has_one_attached :img` in the model as well. I'd like to also share what I got in the frontend.

This is the route as suggested by a post I read.

```
post '/img' => 'albums#img'
```

This is how I'm doing the form.

```
<label for="img">Select image:</label>
            <input type="file" id="img" name="img" accept="image/*" class="border-2 rounded-sm border-gray-500" ><br><be>
```

And this would be the function for the submit event listener.

```
function bindAlbumFormEventListener() {
    albumForm.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        const body = new FormData()
        const newImg = document.querySelector("#img").files[0]
        body.append('file', newImg)
        // body.append('album_id', album.id)
        fetch("http://localhost:3000/img",{
            method: "POST",
            body
        })
        const name = document.getElementById("name").value
        const artist = document.getElementById("artist").value
        const img = document.getElementById("img").src
        const genre = document.getElementById("genre").value
        const category_id = document.getElementById("category_id").value
        const condition = document.getElementById("condition").value
        const description = document.getElementById("description").value
        const price = document.getElementById("price").value;
        const data = {
            name,
            artist,
            img,
            genre,
            category_id,
            condition,
            description,
            price,
        };
        submitAlbum(data)
        albumForm.reset()
    })
}
```

I've been debugging a lot tonight, but there are all kinds of errors. This is what I got after my last effort.

```
ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature (ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature):
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to get Rails to upload the image and JavaScript to pick it up and post it with the albums I'm creating?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems that the `file_url = Cloudinary::Uploader.upload(params[:file], options = {})` is not initialized with your Cloudinary credentials. There an [article by Bruna](https://hackernoon.com/image-storage-in-rails-apps-using-cloudinary-and-active-storage-9w2u3yli) describing how to set the Cloudinary parameters for ActiveStorage.

Comment: Thanks for the article. However, my images are updating to cloudinary. But, I can't still create them from the frontend form. Please refer to the new version of this question.